# Confirm if my entity is saved using doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

After I persist and existing or a new entity using entity manager, How do I confirm whether this entity is saved?

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your entity has an auto generated value column like *id*:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

you may check if the entity was saved by doing

```
if($entity->getId())
```

Comment: what if the entity i am saving already have an ID value and I am updating it?

Comment: It will throw an exception. You may want to analyze the following code: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L301

Comment: Give me +1 (up arrow on left of my answer) if this helped you. Thanks